# Python casting base class object to subclass using dataclass

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have an Employee base class and a Manager subclass. The subclass accepts an Employee obj and converts it to Manager.

The below code works fine, however I am trying to determine how I can create the same using a dataclass.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, id: int, name: str):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

class Manager(Employee):
    def __init__(self, employee: Employee, region: str):
        super().__init__(**vars(employee))
        self.region = region

e1 = Employee(1, 'Bob')
e2 = Employee(2, 'Sally')

# Sally gets promoted to manager of southwest region
e2 = Manager(e2, 'southwest')
```

Here is what I have so far, I'm not sure how to pass all the required parameters.

```
@dataclass
class Employee:
    id: int
    name: str

@dataclass
class Manager(Employee):
    region: str
    def __new__(cls, employee: Employee, region: str):
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        super().__init__(obj, **vars(employee))
        return obj

e2 = Employee(2, 'Sally')
```

```
>>> Manager(e2, region='southwest')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what all of the `__new__` metaclass hackery is meant to be accomplishing, but you very seldom need to override `__new__` in Python, and this is no exception.

```
@dataclass
class Employee:
    id: int
    name: str

@dataclass
class Manager(Employee):
    region: str

e2 = Employee(2, 'Sally')
m2 = Manager(2, 'Sally', 'southwest')
```

Dataclasses are just that; classes meant to store data. Inheritance on dataclasses works like you'd expect. Just inherit and it all works out.

If you'd still rather take an `Employee` as argument, you can use `__init__` rather than `__new__`

```
@dataclass
class Employee:
    id: int
    name: str

@dataclass
class Manager(Employee):
    region: str
    def __init__(self, employee: Employee, region: str):
        super().__init__(**vars(employee))
        self.region = region
```

Comment: Ideally I'd like to pass the e2 obj to the Manager class and have the attributes assigned without having to specify each one. Especially in a case where Employee has hundreds of attributes.

Comment: I tried using ```__new__``` because it get's called before ```__init__```, so it gives me a chance to pass ```e2.__dict__``` to super.

Comment: See my edit then. It looks to me like `__init__` still works fine. If that doesn't work for you, feel free to clarify, and we can take another look.